# Stop gnuplot interpolating heatmaps

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data as a heat map in gnuplot. My data is a ".txt" file with three columns. The first two columns are the independent variables and the third is the output. 
E.g, a simplified example:

```
0.00 0.00 11.9
0.00 0.50 0.01
0.50 0.00 4.5
0.50 0.50 20.0

gnuplot> set view map; set dgrid3d; splot "output.txt" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

I expect to get a 2*2 array of squares with colours according to their value. Instead, I think gnuplot has interpolated the values as regardless of my initial number of data points, it plots a 9*9 array of squares with shading. How can I just plot the data I have with no interpolation?
[output from gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuXPS.png)

Comment: Read `help dgrid3d`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `plot ... with image pixels`. The script below generates a png file with only 4 pixels, colored by their z-value:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "0.00 0.00 11.9
0.00 0.50 0.01
0.50 0.00 4.5
0.50 0.50 20.0" > output.txt

gnuplot << GNUPLOT 

set term png
set out  "output.png"

plot "output.txt" using 1:2:3 with image pixels

GNUPLOT

rm output.txt
```

The `output.png` file should behave the way you expect (hopefully)!

[image]

You can also tweak the cbtics to print only the values on the third column. I would also suggest looking at these two `gnuplot` man pages:

[gnuplot heatmaps](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html)

[gnuplot pm3d](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3d.html)

Comment: You mean "he script below generates a PNG" ? :)

Comment: Yeap, I changed my mind on the pdf example, but forgot to edit the answer. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: No need to set the view and exit explicitly.

Comment: Fair enough! I removed those lines, and now it looks cleaner. Thanks